# Potentioal memory leak with spread operator?

Tags: javascript, node.js, deep-copy, shallow-copy

I'm just wondering if the following code snippet is a potential memory leak.

```js
let arrOfObj = [
    { a: 0, b: 0 }
]

const copy = [ ...arrOfObj ]
copy[0].a = 5;
console.log(arrOfObj)
// [ { a: 5, b: 0 } ]
console.log(copy)
// [ { a: 5, b: 0 } ]

arrOfObj = []
console.log(arrOfObj)
// []
console.log(copy)
// [ { a: 5, b: 0 } ]
```

The spread operator will only do a shallow copy, so the object inside the array would be a reference. But where did javascript get the values in the last log? Will they garbage collected as I empty the array?

Comment: You didn’t empty any array. You just reassigned the `arrOfObj` variable to a new array. See [How do I empty an array in JavaScript?](/q/1232040/4642212).

Comment: After your statement 2, copy and arrOfObj are two seperate arrays. The object inside is the same. Anything you do to the **array** itself after that, will not change anything in the other array. Only the object reference is the same

Comment: Nothing in the global scope is garbage collected.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no memory leak. Breaking down the steps for better explanation:

1. `const copy = [...arrOfObj]` : allocates space in memory heap and assign it to `copy` variable. Since, spread performs shallow copy, the object reference is still same inside of the array.
2. `copy[0].a = 5;` : updates the value of the object inside of `copy` array. Since, the reference to object is same for both `copy` and `arrOfObj`, it is reflected in both the arrays.
3. `arrOfObj = []` : allocates space in memory heap for `[]` and assigns it to `arrOfObj` variable. This does not imply that `copy` loses its reference to the array you created earlier. `copy` still points to the older memory reference. Hence, `copy` prints out the older array containing object, and `arrOfObj` prints empty array.

To ellaborate more on this, even if you do the following, `copy` would still point to older memory reference :

```js
let arrOfObj = [
    { a: 0, b: 0 }
]

// instead of spread, assign it directly 
const copy = arrOfObj;
copy[0].a = 5;
console.log(arrOfObj)
// [ { a: 5, b: 0 } ]
console.log(copy)
// [ { a: 5, b: 0 } ]

// assign empty array to 'arrOfObj'
arrOfObj = []
console.log(arrOfObj)
// []
console.log(copy)
// [ { a: 5, b: 0 } ] => still prints the array
```

Also, the older value of `arrOfObj` "may" get garbage collected (depends on JS engine optimisations)

Comment: To elaborate on the "why?": Variables/Constants in JS do not hold a value by themselves, they are all references to anonymous values in memory. With an assignment like `x = 5;`, you technically do not say "put value 5 into variable `x`", you say "here is the value 5, let variable `x` reference it". The previous value referenced by variable `x` is now somewhere in memory and will be garbage collected when no variable/datastructure references it anymore. (In languages without garbage collector (e.g. Pascal), it would be technically correct to say "put value 5 into variable `x`")

Comment: So, it is save to work with the copy cause it "may" be garbage collected?

Comment: @LeonBraun no, `copy` will always refer to the value, hence, it should be safe to use. I was referring to the old value of `arrOfObj` which can potentially get garbage collected.